# Gmail Inbox Feed doesn't work with OAuth anymore

Tags: oauth, rss, gmail, feed, inbox

Gmail Inbox Feed
(https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) stopped working (401 response) if passing an OAuth access token via the Authorization header.

Does anybody know if this is just a temporary glitch of if it isn't supported anymore? Thanks.

Comment: It's just a temporary glitch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345054/gmail-atom-feed-with-2-legged-oauth-receive-401-error

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks!

Comment: It started working again this morning.