# Access to Gmail Atom feed with OAuth2 from Android app stopped working

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, gmail, atom-feed

I have an Android app, which could access the Gmail Atom inbox feed for read-only access to unread emails (that's all I need). And, it recently stopped working.

It is using *OAuth2* and *GoogleAuthUtil*. This how it works, with use of AsyncTask in a Service:

**First, get a token:**

```
String scope = "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/";
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountName ,scope );
```

**Then use it to read the feed:**

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();                 
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);                                      
connection.connect();
//get the insputStream, read it, etc.
```

Problem is that **this was working** for approx. 1 month (May/June 2014). The app is even published on GooglePlay and has users. **It was working and tested on different devices, different accounts, etc. I'm not 100% sure that it stopped working on all installations, but I can not get it back to work for myself and my devices.** The app accessed the feed approx. every 10-20 minutes (based on user setting).

Do you have any idea why this could happend?

Since few days, I can still obtain the token, but response is only **Unauthorized (401)** response:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1><H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

- I tried:

  - to invalidate the token every time
  - to fiddle with the scope
  - to rewoke access in my accounts settings
  - to reinstall
  - to update the Google-Play-Services library

etc., with no result.

After some research, I know about a client-id which needs to be generated to access various google APIs. I was able to generated such ID.

I tried to use that ID - to include it in the scope and run the app from a signed APK. **But I cannot find any API in the list** (https://console.developers.google.com) which could say GMAIL or ATOM FEED, or anything related to gmail. So I am unable to use it.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT - SOLVED**
Google resolved the issue, updated something :-) - now it works again.

Comment: Right now the service is not working. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345054/gmail-atom-feed-with-2-legged-oauth-receive-401-error

Comment: Thank you very much!! That is a sad news, but at least I know what's going on.

Comment: Update - still the same bug.